# conjugate matrix $A^*=A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n$ and $A^*$ is conjugate of $A$.
Suppose that $A=A^*$
prove that $det(A)\in R$.
My work:
$$det(A) = det(A^*) = det(A^{t \ conjudate.})$$
now i want to say that 
$$det(A^{t \ conjudate.}) = det(A^t) conjudate $$
and from here it is easy to complete the proof.
is this step is right? 
thanks for helping.

Comment: Usually the star sign is used to denote the conjugate transpose in which case, all eigenvalues are real and so is the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's right. To prove it let $B=(b_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ a matrix then

$$\det(\overline B)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\prod_{k=1}^n\epsilon(\sigma)\overline{b_{\sigma(k),k}}=\overline{\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\prod_{k=1}^n\epsilon(\sigma){b_{\sigma(k),k}}}=\overline{\det(B)}$$